# Apache and 504 Errors

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I'm using `Apache` and `Tomcat` with `mod_jk`.

My Apache server has been unpredictably responding with `504 errors` (server too slow to respond or proxy too impatient) when a client asks for files of size 15-20 KB.

Apache should be serving up these static XML files, so I believe it's an Apache issue.

What should I be looking for in my Apache logs when trying to figure out the source of the 504 errors?